# VS2008: No option to convert Win32 C++ project to x64?

Tags: c++, 64-bit

I am running VS Team System 2008 on WinXP. I make a new Win32 C++ project (Empty project). I go to Build Configuration to add a configuration for x64.

The only options I have are:
- Pocket PC 2003 (ARMV4)
- Smartphone 2003 (ARMV4)

I have no option for x64 (or Itanium). However, if I make a C# project within the same solution, I can create and select an x64 option for that project with no issues. But even then, when the x64 build configuration has been created, I still cannot select it for the C++ project - only for the C# project.

I have done this before on another system - creating an x64 config for a Win32 C++ project. But I can't do it now. Any ideas why? Something small/obvious no doubt, since google has offered no help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you didn't install the native x64 compiler.

Try to run setup again, and look if you selected the native x64 C++ compiler.

Comment: That's precisely what it turned out to be for the guy in the next cube here.

Comment: Yes, spot on, clear as day once I re-ran the installer. Thanks.